# React Native listen for keyboard press events

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

How do you globally listen for keyboard events? I have a PanResponder listening for all touch and press events but it doesn't record keyboard touches (assumingely because the keyboard is not part of my app). The React Native Keyboard Api on records show and dismiss.

Comment: Why would your Keyboard be visible on a PanResponder ?

Comment: It wouldn't I was just explaining that I need some way to track the events like a pan responder does

Answer (score 0):

The PanResponder -- and more generally, all touch-related APIs on mobile -- don't expose key presses. You need to create a text input component and look at its events.

Comment: Obviously my question was how to do that global,  I don't want to have to pass a callback to each OnChangeText